# Two jQuery Animations on the same pages causes non smooth transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I have something like this

```
<hgroup id="ticker">

<div>
 <h1>First <span>Div</span></h1>
 <h2>This is the First Div</h2>
 <h6>This is the First Heading</h6>
</div>

<div>
 <h1>Second <span>Div</span></h1>
 <h2>This is the Second Div</h2>
 <h6>This is the Second Heading</h6>
</div>

<!-- And so on -->

</hgroup>
```

And I use

```
<script>
var $ticker = $('#ticker'); // save the static element
$ticker.children(':not(:first-child)').hide();

function tick(){
$ticker.children(':first-child').fadeOut(1000, function () {
    $(this).appendTo($ticker);
    $ticker.children().first().fadeIn(1000);
});
}
setInterval(tick, 8000);
</script>
```

It works ok. No problems with it. Maybe needs refactoring but I am just getting many hands dirty with jQuery. And Than I have

```
<div id="quote">
 <blockquote>This is the First quote<span class="dim"><strong>1</strong></span></blockquote>
 <blockquote>This is the First quote<span class="dim"><strong>1</strong></span></blockquote>
</div>

<!-- And so on -->
```

And I use

```
<script>
var $quote = $('#quote');
$quote.children(':not(:first-child)').hide();

function tick(){
$quote.children(':first-child').slideUp(1000, function () {
    $(this).appendTo($quote);
    $quote.children().first().slideDown(1000);
});
}
setInterval(tick, 8000);
</script>
```

But what this does is that the animation is not smooth. The fade and slide pauses, resumes, flickers and the animation/transition is not smooth or fluid.

Any single one without the other works ok but taken together on the same pages causes this issue.

Also note I can half understand the jQuery code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/za8WK/1/)

Try this,

```
var $quote = $('#quote');
$quote.children(':not(:first-child)').hide();

function tick() {
    $quote.children(':first-child').stop().slideUp(1000, function () {
        $(this).appendTo($quote);
        $quote.children().stop().first().slideDown(1000);
    });
}
setInterval(tick, 8000);
```